# Comparison of music data

Tags: comparison, string-comparison

I am looking for theory, algorithms and similar for how to compare music. More specifically, I am looking into how to dupecheck music tracks that have different bitrates or perhaps slightly different variations (radio vs album version), but otherwise sound the same.

Use cases for this include services such as Grooveshark, Youtube, etc. where they get a **lot** of duplicate tracks. I am also interested in text comparisons (Britney Spers vs Britney Spears, how far they deviate, etc.) although this is secondary and I already have some sources to go on in this area.

I am mostly interested in codec-agnostic comparison techniques and algoritms (assuming a "raw" stream), but codec-specific resources are appreciated.

I am aware of projects such as musicbrainz.org, but have not investigated it further, and would be interested if such projects could be of help in this endeavor.

Comment: If you are going to write a tool which looks at the actual audio data: checking for abrupt endings (damaged files or just crappy rips where the end is missing are hard to find manually if your music collection is not very small unless you write down whenever you notice a song ending abrubtly which is unlikely if you are doing something else while listening to music)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a similar answer here: [Music Recognition and Signal Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068286/music-recognition-and-signal-processing/2072606#2072606).

In the research community, the problem of finding similarity between two signals (up to environmental distortions such as noise, mild variations in tempo, pitch, or bitrate) is known as *[audio (or music) fingerprinting](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=audio+fingerprinting&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=20000001&as_sdtp=on)*. This topic has been studied heavily for at least a decade. This early (and oft cited) [paper by Haitsma and Kalker](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.2175&rep=rep1&type=pdf) clearly describes the problem and proposes a simple solution.

The problem of finding musical similarity between two versions of the same song is known as *[cover song identification](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=cover+song+identification&btnG=Search&as_sdt=20000000&as_ylo=&as_vis=0)*. This problem is also studied heavily but is still considered open.

Perhaps the two most popular commercial solutions for content-based musical search are [Midomi](http://www.midomi.com/) and [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/).

I believe this addresses your question. Check Google Scholar for recent solutions to these problems. The [ISMIR](http://www.ismir.net/) proceedings are available for free online.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the type of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

As far as comparing names is concerned you might want to take a look at the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm. Given two strings it will calculate a distance measurement which can be used as a basis for catching duplicates.

I personally have used it in a tool I developed for an application with a rather large database that had a large number of duplicates in it. Using it in conjunction with some other data comparisons relevant to my domain I was able to point my tool at the application database and quickly find many of the duplicated records. Not going to lie, I thought it was pretty darn cool to see in action.

It's even quick to implement, here's a [C# version](http://www.merriampark.com/ldcsharp.htm):

```
public int CalculateDistance(string s, string t) {
    int n = s.Length; //length of s
    int m = t.Length; //length of t
    int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1]; // matrix
    int cost; // cost

    // Step 1
    if (n == 0) return m;
    if (m == 0) return n;

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++) ;
    for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++) ;
    // Step 3
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        //Step 4
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            // Step 5
            cost = (t.Substring(j - 1, 1) == s.Substring(i - 1, 1) ? 0 : 1);

            // Step 6
            d[i, j] = System.Math.Min(System.Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1), d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }

    // Step 7
    return d[n, m];
}
```

Comment: I know of the algorithm and was intending to use it for weeding out the "easy" targets, however some artists have the same name and there is an overlap where simple text comparison won't do, which is why I'm looking for something domain specific for music data.