# OpenCV: Fast way to compare frames for similarity

Tags: c++, image, opencv, similarity

I'm looking for a fast way to compare a frame with a running average, and determine the difference between them (in terms of giving a high value if they're very similar, and a lower value if they're not that similar). I need to compare the entire frame, not just a smaller region.

I'm already using Otsu thresholding on the images to filter out the background (not interested in the background, nor the features of the foreground - just need shapes). Is there a nice, fast way to do what I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple and fast method to compare images for similarity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196453/simple-and-fast-method-to-compare-images-for-similarity)

Answer (score 3):

The *classic* method for this is **Normalized Cross Correlation** (try `cv::matchTemplate()`). You will need to set a treshold to decided if images are a match. Also you can use the output (which is thresholded) to compare several images.

In OpenCV, this method in matchTemplate is explained [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#which-are-the-matching-methods-available-in-opencv), and the parameter you need to pass to the function.