# Android Image Processiing

Tags: android, image-processing

In my application I want to capture an image and compare it with a stored image to know if they are similar.
What API/technology/third party application can I use to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OpenCV library:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

Take a look at this answer for ideas how to solve your problem:
[Simple and fast method to compare images for similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196453/simple-and-fast-method-to-compare-images-for-similarity)