# How to compare two images using Node.js

Tags: node.js, image-processing, automated-tests, image-comparison

I am looking for a way to compare two images to see how similar they are. Googling it produces tons of image processing results (cropping, re-sizing, etc.), but nothing that would do approximate comparisons of images. There is one Node.js library, but it is version 0.0.1 and relies on various 3rd party system packages, so not stable or portable.

Something along these lines:

```
var imgComparator = require('some-awesome-image-comparator-module');
// result would be between 1.0 and 0.0, where 1.0 would mean exact match
var result = imgComparator.compare('/path/to/image/1.png', '/path/to/image/2.png');
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) module, you might use it in order to perform heavy operation like image comparison. Good topic on that is here: [Simple and fast method to compare images for similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196453/simple-and-fast-method-to-compare-images-for-similarity)

Answer (score 13):

There is also [image-diff](https://github.com/uber/image-diff) which looks very promising, it's made by Uber.

```
var imageDiff = require('image-diff')

imageDiff({
  actualImage: 'checkerboard.png',
  expectedImage: 'white.png'
}, function (err, imagesAreSame) {
  // error will be any errors that occurred
  // imagesAreSame is a boolean whether the images were the same or not
  // diffImage will have an image which highlights differences
})
```

Comment: does this require the images be identical? I'm looking to compare if two images are similar. ie: same photo of same building, but slightly different because its not the same photo.

Comment: fwiw, image-diff is a thin wrapper around imagemagick/graphicsmagick's `compare` tool.

Comment: Deprecated in favor of [looks-same](https://github.com/gemini-testing/looks-same) and [pixelmatch](https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch).

Answer (score 10):

[image-diff](https://github.com/uber-archive/image-diff) is deprecated.

From their github:

> We no longer have any active maintainers on this project and as a
>   result have halted maintenance.
>
> As a replacement, please see alternative projects like looks-same and
>   pixelmatch:
>
> https://github.com/gemini-testing/looks-same
>
> https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch

I personally use pixelmatch:

> The smallest, simplest and fastest JavaScript pixel-level image
>   comparison library, originally created to compare screenshots in
>   tests.
>
> Features accurate anti-aliased pixels detection and perceptual color
>   difference metrics.
>
> Inspired by Resemble.js and Blink-diff. Unlike these libraries,
>   pixelmatch is around 150 lines of code, has no dependencies, and works
>   on raw typed arrays of image data, so it's blazing fast and can be
>   used in any environment (Node or browsers).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;
const pixelmatch = require('pixelmatch');

const img1 = PNG.sync.read(fs.readFileSync('img1.png'));
const img2 = PNG.sync.read(fs.readFileSync('img2.png'));
const {width, height} = img1;
const diff = new PNG({width, height});

const difference = pixelmatch(img1.data, img2.data, diff.data, width, height, {threshold: 0.1});

fs.writeFileSync('diff.png', PNG.sync.write(diff)); // see diff.png for the difference

const compatibility = 100 - dif * 100 / (width * height);
console.log(`${difference} pixels differents`);
console.log(`Compatibility: ${compatibility}%`);
```

Find a demo here: https://observablehq.com/@mourner/pixelmatch-demo

https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch

Comment: But pixel match is working only with PNG, I have a similar issue with the author, I need to compare 2 jpg images with using nodeJS, and pixel match doesn't work for this...

Comment: You can use [`sharp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) to convert from different formats to a PNG/PNG buffer

Answer (score 3):

I have found this library, which may be useful for you

https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/js-imagediff

Comment: Please keep me up to date, because I did not make it work yet :).

Comment: There's an example of how to use the lib in "bin/imagediff". Use the save version of the canvas module as imagediff, the newest one seems to be incompatible. Read the manual of how to install canvas and cairo. I got stuck a long time because I missed that I needed to add a folder to my PATH.