# How to compare two Images using nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need to compare below image urls:

https://cdn-image.foodandwine.com/sites/default/files/original-201404-HD-buckwheat-crepes.jpg
https://test-static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2014/04/original-201404-HD-buckwheat-crepes.jpg

Please provide solution.

Comment: What do you mean by that, you want to compare urls or you want to compare the content of image is exactly same or not ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two images using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510897/how-to-compare-two-images-using-node-js)

Comment: See also [Compare two Images in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066111/compare-two-images-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

The smallest, simplest and fastest JavaScript pixel-level image comparison library, originally created to compare screenshots in tests.

Features accurate anti-aliased pixels detection and perceptual color difference metrics.

Inspired by Resemble.js and Blink-diff. Unlike these libraries, pixelmatch is around 150 lines of code, has no dependencies, and works on raw typed arrays of image data, so it's blazing fast and can be used in any environment.

By this library, you can easily compare the images.

```
const numDiffPixels = pixelmatch(img1, img2, diff, 800, 600, {threshold: 0.1});
```

Answer (score -6):

```
var url1 = "https://cdn-image.foodandwine.com/sites/default/files/original-201404-HD-buckwheat-crepes.jpg";
var url2 = "https://test-static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2014/04/original-201404-HD-buckwheat-crepes.jpg";
if (url1 === url2) {
    //is equal
} else {
    //not equal
}
```

Comment: That would be comparing `URL` of the image. Not the actual content.

Comment: For sure. He want's to compare the images not image sources

Comment: oh, so it does matter ;)

Comment: I want to compare images.

Comment: sure but you should provide more informations, and previous effort

Comment: it is also why people dislike your post

Comment: To be honest i really don't know anything about js and nodejs...I tried opencv and pixelmatch but am not able to achieve it. If possible please help me

Comment: You need to `npm install pixelmatch` first to use the library

Here is everything you should need:

`const pixelmatch = require('pixelmatch');`

`const img1 = Buffer.from("https://cdn-image.foodandwine.com/sites/default/files/original-201404-HD-buckwheat-crepes.jpg");`
`const img2 = Buffer.from("https://cdn-image.foodandwine.com/sites/default/files/original-201404-HD-buckwheat-crepes.jpg");`
`const numDiffPixels = pixelmatch(img1, img2, null, <width>, <height>);`

`console.log(numDiffPixels);`

<width> and <height> should be replaced by the correct image with and height

Comment: use https://beautifier.io to make the code readable