# Comparing 2 images/pictures by using PIL, some doesn't work

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am comparing 2 images/pictures by using PIL. Below codes work on some pictures but not all.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageDraw

im1 = Image.open(r'c:\a.jpg')
im2 = Image.open(r'c:\aa.jpg')

diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1).getbbox()

print diff

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.rectangle(diff)
im2 = im2.convert('RGB')
im2.save(r'c:\aaa.jpg')
```

For example, it doesn’t work for these 2 pictures.

a.jpg
[image]

aa.jpg
[image]

the output is (16, 80, 80, 144) however it doesn't draw anything on the picture.

Questions:

1. Why is it happening?
2. Does the file type matter? i.e. JPG compares with JPG; PNG compares with PNG; BMP compares with BMP – which format is best for comparison?
3. Sometimes the difference lies on far distance on the picture, so it will draw a big rectangle to include the whole area. Is there a way to only draw small rectangle to mark the differeces?

Thanks.

Comment: does your rectangle call need a colour?

Comment: in the openCV package, you can grab various areas of change based upon the intensity difference. for a primer: http://opencvpython.blogspot.ca/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt draw enything, maybe check by chenging color of the rectangle, `draw.rectangle(diff, outline  = (0,255,0))`

Comment: thanks, user1269942. I will read the tutorial.

Comment: @Marcin, thanks for the tip. anybody any idea if file format such as PNG, JPG, BMP etc matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageDraw

im1 = Image.open('a.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('aa.jpg')

diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1).getbbox()

print diff

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.rectangle(diff, outline = (0,255,0))
print  help(draw.rectangle)
im2 = im2.convert('RGB')
im2.save('aaa.jpg')
```

> Help on method rectangle in module PIL.ImageDraw:
>
> rectangle(self, xy, fill=None, outline=None) method of
>   PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw instance

So the **outline** parameter is **None** by default that's why its creating transparent rectangle here.

[image]

Comment: thanks. it solved the problem. actually they are quite the same but deemed different, is there a less 'sensitive' way to compare pictures? I mean only pictures are identically different can only deemed as different.

Comment: If you are going for Image comparison or searching any object on Images etc i would really suggest you to go for opencv. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196453/simple-and-fast-method-to-compare-images-for-similarity