# Calculate similarity of picture and its sketch

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, similarity

I'm trying to develop algorithm, which returns similarity score for two given black and white images: original one and its sketch, drawn by human:

[image]

All original images has the same style, but there is no any given limited set of them. Their content could be totally different.

I've tried few approaches, but none of them was successful yet:

### OpenCV template matching

OpenCV matchTemplate is not able to calculate *similarity* score of images. It could only tells me count of matched pixels, and this value is usually quite low, because of not ideal proportions of human's sketch.

### OpenCV feature matching

I've failed with this method, because I couldn't find good algorithms for extracting *significant* features from human's sketch. Algorithms from [OpenCV's tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html) are good in extracting corners and blobs as features.  But here, in sketches, we have a lot of strokes - each of them produces a lot of insignificant, junk features and leads to fuzzy results.

### Neural Network Classification

Also I took a look at neural networks - they are good in image classification, but also they need train sets for each of classes, and this part is impossible, because we have an unlimited set of possible images.

Which methods and algorithms would you use for this kind of task?

Comment: have a look at chamfer matching. You'll need to find ways to make it scale- and rotational invariant. Other shape matching algorithms might be good, too. And have a look at active contours!

Comment: How about crosscorrelation? You can get best matching pixel position, then you can align the images and calculate the similarity score

Comment: How about 'cosine - similarity', given the fact that they are binary images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### METHOD 1

**Cosine similarity** gives a similarity score ranging between (0 - 1).

I first converted the images to gray scale and binarized them. I cropped the original image to half the size and excluded the text as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I then converted the image arrays to 1D arrays using `flatten()`. I used the following to compute *cosine similarity*:

```
from scipy import spatial
result = spatial.distance.cosine(im2, im1)
print result
```

The result I obtained was **0.999999988431**, meaning the images are similar to each other by this score.

**EDIT**

### METHOD 2

I had the time to check out another solution. I figured out that OpenCV's `cv2.matchTemplate()` function performs the same job.

I f you check out [THIS DOCUMENTATION PAGE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) you will come across the different parameters used.

I used the `cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED` parameter (which gives the normalized square difference between the two images).

```
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(th1, th2, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
    print 1 - res
```

For the given images I obtained a similarity score of: `0.89689457`

Comment: Also check [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196453/simple-and-fast-method-to-compare-images-for-similarity?rq=1)

Comment: can you please sir tell how did you convert image to 1D array?

Comment: @0x01Brain `np.flatten()` from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Comment: I tried that but it returns nothing when doing: `spatial.distance.cosine(im2, im1)`

Comment: I mean it returns 0.0 always why?

Comment: @0x01Brain same thing, it returned 0.0 to me also