# How to measure the similarity between two gray level images?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, grayscale

I have 2 gray-level images and want to measure the similarity between two images using subtraction and opencv.
I tried to subtract the images and count black pixels but some values may be under 0 so I guess they will be displayed as 0 and that means this way is not so accurate.
I need a way to find the percentage using subtraction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple and fast method to compare images for similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196453/simple-and-fast-method-to-compare-images-for-similarity)

Comment: I don't think using a color based similarity check will work.

Comment: Not sure what sort of differences you are expecting to detect, but there's nothing stopping you from converting to float (or signed integer) to be able to detect/record negative numbers.

Comment: What, specifically, is your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Convert you images to float. The subtract. Then take the absolute value.  See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/. Have you considered using SSIM? See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to measure similarity or differences in images.
The request you are asking is specifically for [L1 Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

For a quick and simple solution just take the absolute value.