# How to detect sound frequency for particular sound in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, signal-processing

I'm doing an app where I want to detect sound frequency. How to detect frequency for particular sound like dog sound? Does anybody have tutorial or some sample codes?

Comment: A dog barking doesn't have a particular *frequency* - it has a complex time-varying *spectrum*.

Comment: your right but how to compare two sound are same

Comment: It's a very complex subject - you typically convert the sound to the frequency domain and then perform feature extraction so that you can compare features of an incoming sound with a database of reference features.

Comment: @Bing Consider marking as answer if your question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting a single frequency, or even computing a single FFT, is not a reliable method for differentiating a dog bark from other common sounds of around the same volume.

What might work is sound fingerprint analysis using MFCC's, followed by statistical pattern matching against a large enough "dog" sound database.  Some pointers to the type of signal processing required might be answered here: [Music Recognition and Signal Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068286/music-recognition-and-signal-processing)

This is non-trivial stuff more suited for multiple college textbook chapters than any short tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the frequency, you can use a pitch detection algorithm like FFT.

Learn more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm

You can look at this project for working source code for iOS that uses FFT algorithm to detect frequencies:
https://github.com/hollance/SimonSings

Comment: Here is a more stripped down example of FFT pitch tracking, with a tutorial explanation: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Comment: FFT is a naive way to detect pitch: even if you find the global maximum in the frequency domain, that could still be an harmonic.

Comment: @ValentinRadu You are right. FFT is just one of the ways, and not be the best.

Comment: There are ways to deal with avoiding harmonics, one of which is to use a filter (which is what I do in my tutorial). Comparing FFT and time-domain methods and simply saying one is "best" depends on many factors.